# How to dynamically set the class of a function argument?

Tags: java, eclipse, dynamic, dynamic-programming, abstract-syntax-tree

For a Compilers' project, I have to find a pattern in a Java file. For example, if I input "@x = 3" the program must return every occasion on which 3 is attributed to something.

For that, I am using [ASTParser](http://help.eclipse.org/luna/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.jdt.doc.isv%2Freference%2Fapi%2Forg%2Feclipse%2Fjdt%2Fcore%2Fdom%2FAST.html) from JDT. I parse the file and get a CompilationUnit object, like so:

```
private static CompilationUnit getAST(char[] unit){

    ASTParser parser = ASTParser.newParser(AST.JLS8); 
    parser.setKind(ASTParser.K_COMPILATION_UNIT);
    parser.setSource(unit); // set source

    parser.setResolveBindings(true); // we need bindings later on
    parser.setBindingsRecovery(true);

    Map options = JavaCore.getOptions();
    parser.setCompilerOptions(options);

    CompilationUnit cu = (CompilationUnit) parser.createAST(null);

    return cu;  

}
```

Now, what I'm doing is building another AST based on the pattern I was given. The example above results in something like:

```
AssignementExpression
 LHS
  Pattern("@x")
 RHS
  Literal("3")
```

Then I use this AST to search the CompilationUnit. The problem is that the ASTParser API [class](http://help.eclipse.org/mars/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.jdt.doc.isv%2Freference%2Fapi%2Forg%2Feclipse%2Fjdt%2Fcore%2Fdom%2FASTVisitor.html) to search nodes needs to know the class of the node I'm visiting.

I need to create a new visitor object and define what I want to do in the visit function:

```
ASTVisitor visitor = (new ASTVisitor() {

        public boolean visit(VariableDeclarationFragment node) {

            // what I want to do

            return true; // do not continue 
        }
}
```

So what I want to do is, in runtime, associate AssignementExpression with VariableDeclarationFragment and call the visit function with VariableDeclarationFragment. Something like:

```
Class nodeType = getTypeFromGrammar("AssignementExpression");

ASTVisitor visitor = (new ASTVisitor() {

        public boolean visit(nodeType node) { // use the class that was returned above

            // what I want to do

            return true; // do not continue 
        }
}
```

Comment: I'm not sure I understand. How could I use the cast to call a visit with the class I want to?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One approach is to use reflection.

You'll want to use a named subclass of ASTVisitor rather than an anonymous class. Let's say it's called MyAstVisitor. It can override multiple of the `ASTVisitor.visit(T)` methods.

You can get the appropriate method with [Class.getMethod()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#getMethod-java.lang.String-java.lang.Class...-). For example:

```
Method visitMethod = MyASTVistor.class.getMethod( "visit", nodeType );
```

Then you can invoke the method with [Method.invoke()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/reflect/Method.html#invoke-java.lang.Object-java.lang.Object...-):

```
visitMethod.invoke( myAstVisitorInstance, myNode );
```

Comment: Ok. I was not considering creating a new subclass which I could control. I will try to make it as you say and come back with feedback.

Comment: Your examples show the creation of an anonymous subclass. If you don't want a subclass, you can use `ASTVisitor.class.getMethod(...)`.

Comment: Yes, I know. But I did not remember that creating a subclass would be the nicest way to do it. I finally got it to work. Thanks!